# Webpack bundle not executed on node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I am using webpack along with express. For my front-end I am using react.js. Webpack creates a bundle.js file which is executed on the client side (since it is js file). I am trying to use node server to serve the files to client.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.end(
    '<html>' + 
    '<head>' + 
        '<script src="bundle.js"></script>' +
    '</head>' +
    '<body>' + 
        '<div id="header">'+
        '</div>' +
        '<div id= "left-side-bar">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div id = "right-side-bar">' +
        '</div>'+
    '</body>' + 
    '</html>'
    );
});
```

Bundle.js file is being served to the client but its not being executed. I dont see any errors in the console also. The same bundle is being excuted with webpack dev server. What might be the reason for this.

Comment: Maybe it is served as a text file. What is Content-Type for bundle.js when served from your express server?

Comment: You might need a forward slash `/` before bundle.js unless it's hiding in another directory.